# Receber conteúdo em Text de outra página

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, request

estou envolvido em um projeto e no atual momento preciso de receber um conteúdo de uma page (no caso, esta: `http://150.165.202.10/` -> online e funcionando). Tento fazê-lo através do código abaixo que usa Ajax, no entanto, não recebo nada via console ou mesmo no alert. Qual seria uma solução plausível?

Trecho do código:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://150.165.202.10/', 
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}, 
    dataType:'text', success: function(data)  { 
     alert(data);
  console.log(data)
...
});
```